# ProxyPass HTTPS to other server

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy, mod-ssl

I have a server `frontend.example.com` with public IP. It's Apache (2.4) should proxy the traffic coming for `service1.example.com` (DNS alias to `frontend.example.com`).

`service1.example.com` is a VM on a private LAN (`192.168.56.0`) between the two.

Now, this is easy for HTTP:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName service1.example.com

        ProxyPass / http://192.168.56.2/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.56.2/

        <Location "/">
                Require all granted
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm trying to do the same for HTTPS:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName service1.example.com

        SSLEngine On
        SSLProxyEngine On
        ProxyRequests Off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
        SSLInsecureRenegotiation on
        SSLProxyVerify none
        SSLVerifyClient none
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/example_com.key

        ProxyPass / https://192.168.56.2/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.56.2/

        <Location "/">
                Require all granted
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Trying to access `service1.example.com` via HTTPS returns : **Error during SSL Handshake with remote server**

Security is not my concern here. `service1` **requires** an HTTPS connection to some of its services, that's why I'm not simply proxying HTTPS to HTTP.
I do not want `frontend.example.com` to be involved with SSL. What I would like is that it says "hey, I've got a connection on 443, I'm not dealing with it, I'm just forwarding it to this internal IP, which will take care of it".  I just want it to pass the request on.
Can that be done?

As you can see in the HTTPS configuration above, I've tried to relax security as much as possible (e.g. `SSLInsecureRenegotiation on` is suppose to lower the walls against a man-in-the-middle attack, isn't it?). But nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the only directive I was missing is `SSLProxyCheckPeerName off`. Now it works.